# display number of option value of select tag with respect to onchange of radio button value

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

in this scenario,
there are 4 radio button as 1,2,3,4,and we have select tag with option tag.
so requirement is onchange of radio button, number of option value of select tag should be displayed.
ex:if radio 1 is click, then select tag may have 10 values then first five values should be displayed.
if radio 2 is click,then select tag may have two values then all values should be displayed.
I think pic can explain more.
Please suggest, how to proceed
look at example 
Figure 11–4 Example Select One Components
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnase/index.html
our scenario,is between Genere and Language.
wen I click "Fiction" then, drop down should display only fiction related values and vice versa.fiction related values are list of array.

Comment: show us some code of what you have so far

Comment: Also elaborate on the rules. They are not clear at all